# Square thumbnail generation from non-square images in batch

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, image-processing, image-manipulation

Any light weight batch tool that is free or I can purchase to generate square thumbnails from non-square images in batch?

The thumbnails will be square from the center like you see in Flickr.

I need to run this on a folder for batch processing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Not interested in ImageMagick.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used it this way, but Gimp 2 has a scripting language and batch mode that might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to write a script to do this using netpbm tools;
the main section being `jpegtopnm image001.jpg | pnmcut ... | pnmscale ... | pnmtojpeg > thumbnail001.jpg`

Have your script obtain the dimensions of the image via `pnmfile` to use as parameters to `pnmcut` and `pnmscale`.

Comment: Never heard of this. What framework\language does this belong to?

Comment: I see. jpegtopnm seems Linus\Unix. Does it have .NET version?

Comment: It's open source, http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/. You never specified your platform in your original question; it's all written in good old C.